# External JS file not working in HTML page

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I'm playing with `Bootstrap`, but it seems that I cannot make my external `js script` work.

I loaded at the end of my `HTML` file the following scripts:

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/js/myscript.js"></script>
```

`Jquery` gets loaded first, and then I call my script which is positioned in the `js` folder, which is placed in the root directory.

```
jQuery(function(){
    "use strict";
    $("#services h2").text("Hello World");
)};
```

If I try this simple code in the HTML page it works, but not in the external file.
I tried to read other answers but I couldn't figure where the problem resides. Do I need to set up a LAMP environment to make this work?

Comment: Can you make anything happen using myscript.js? Is it just that particular code or does the page act like it can't find the file?

Comment: Are you trying to run the jQuery bit in `myscript.js`?

Comment: Yes I tried to run that script inside the external file but it doesn't work. It seems like the file is not being loaded, but the src parameter should be right reading answers to other questions

Comment: What does the javascript console say? Are you sure it's supposed to have a leading slash? maybe it should just be "js/myscript.js"

Comment: Is your html file also in root directory?

Comment: Yes indeed, that's why I think the way I wrote it down is right

Comment: Your jQuery function has a typo mistake.  The final brackets are reversed, i.e., )}; should be });   Is this mistake actually in your MyScript.js file? If yes, then that might explain the problem.

Comment: @Roberto I think it was a typo when I wrote it down here, on the file it seems right. Still not working though, I don't know what's missing

Comment: I ran the code in multiple browsers, but was not able to duplicate the problem. It appeared to work fine. Might help to know what you see in your dev console [network tab](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Tools/Network_Monitor). That should tell you if the file is loading.

Answer (score 1):

In external js file place your function inside doc ready function : You can start fixing your problem from there.

```
$("document").ready(function() {
    jQuery(function(){
        $("#services h2").text("Hello World");
   });
});
```

also make sure your /js/myscript.js path is correct. For confirming your JQuery is loaded correctly right-click on loaded page in mozzila > Inspect with Firebug > choose console > then choose JQuerify option which will confirm your jQuery has loaded succesfuly. (Obviously if firebug is not installed, install it!)

Comment: Not sure I follow.  Isn't jQuery(function()... just shorthand for $("document").ready(function() ... ?  Why wrap one in the other?

Answer (score 0):

Take off the `/` before `js/myscript.js`
If you write it this way it would work:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/myscript.js"></script>
```